# fragment's isInLayout() returns false

Tags: android, android-fragments

When should the fragment return true from `isInLayout()` method? In my case it returns false but I can see the fragment, and both `isVisible()` and `isAdded()` return true.

In my activity's onCreate method I'm calling this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FragEventList listFrag = new FragEventList();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_1, listFrag, "list");
transaction.commit();
```

and this is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Later when Loader returns the data, I want to pass the adapter to the fragment like this:

```java
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)");

    Log.i(TAG, "fragment=" + getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("list"));
         
    if (mAdapter != null && data != null) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        FragEventList fragment = (FragEventList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("list");
            
        if (fragment != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "in layout=" + fragment.isInLayout());
            Log.i(TAG, "is added=" + fragment.isAdded());
            Log.i(TAG, "is visible=" + fragment.isVisible());
        }
            
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "onLoadFinished: mAdapter is null");
        onLoaderReset(null);
    }
}
```

but `isInLayout()` returns false.

Comment: Reading the doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isInLayout()), it looks like this method will always return false if you don't include your fragment using the <fragment> tag. It's a way to know if the fragment is "fixed" in the layout or it has been added dynamically.

Comment: ok so basicaly only isAdded/isVisible is really useful in my case

Comment: I think so, maybe you could try doing a very quick and simple project with one fragment added using the <fragment> tag. If that will result in having true as a return value for method isInLayout, it will prove it (you could also reply to your own question by yourself in that case).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When the fragment should return true from isInLayout method?

Fragment will return true when it is part of the layout defined via XML otherwise will return false. [Relevant documentation part.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isInLayout%28%29)